# Combining neural networks with different features but same target

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have a question about how one can go about creating a neural network (or similar) architecture(s) that does the following:

**Example**

> Say I have a model that uses feature 1 and feature 2 to predict a
>   target. That model does not perform well because I am limited to the
>   number of training examples that have a feature 1 and feature 2
>   populated.
>
> If I were to have another neural network with feature 3 and feature 4,
>   and my goal is to predict the same target, how can I go about
>   combining the learning from both models to make the same target
>   prediction.
>
> This continues for several other similar datasets with different
>   features but a common target

**Explanation**

> I am only doing this because not every training example has a feature
>   1, 2, 3 and 4, therefore it cannot be incorporated into a single
>   model. But the only thing in common is that the models are trying to
>   predict the same target.

**Question**

> What machine learning strategy (not just a neural network) would be
>   most appropriate for such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model you describe is built out of 2 core sub-models.

1. Many feature-dependent encoders, one for each feature set. Features 1 and 2 can be combined by part of the model into some hidden representation. Features 3 and 4 would be translated into the same hidden representation, but would have a different sub-model with a different set of parameters to fit.
2. A single feature-independent decoder on top of the hidden representation, to predict your target.

When it comes to fitting the model, each encoder can only use the data where the desired feature set is available. It is fitting a representation to those features, so it needs to see them. But the decoder can be used for all of your data. This will capture the distribution of the targets, which is common because your targets are common.

This sort of model is appropriate when you believe that there is a meaningful hidden representation.  That is, you believe that your feature sets are measuring similar things but in different ways.

That allows you to keep the encoder small, as it is doing a small translation from one way of measuring to another. Translating from the measurements to the target may still be difficult, but because that logic goes in the common decoder it can benefit from all the training data.

---

To make it concrete, a good example use case for such a model would be if if your features were `width`, `height`, `volume`, and `weight`. And let's say your target is shipping `cost`.

It is reasonable to say that the intermediate representation is well described by the concept of `size`. And it is also reasonable to say that translating from `size` to `cost` is an interesting problem in its own right, no matter how you measured `size` originally.

So the model formulation looks something like this:

```
# Feature encoders.
size ~ width + height
size ~ volume + weight

# Target decoder.
cost ~ size
```

---

Now, above I have been careful to describe the model design without any commitment to the type of model. But you did tag this question as related neural networks specifically, and I think that's a good choice.

For your simple example, using PyTorch, the model might look something like this:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class MultiEncoderSingleDecoder(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hid_sz):
        super().__init__()

        self.using_encoder = 0
        self.encoders = torch.nn.ModuleList([
            torch.nn.Linear(2, hid_sz),
            torch.nn.Linear(2, hid_sz),
        ])
        self.decoder = torch.nn.Linear(hid_sz, 1)

    def set_encoder(self, use_encoder):
        self.using_encoder = use_encoder

    def forward(self, inp):
        encoder = self.encoders[self.using_encoder]
        return self.decoder(F.relu(encoder(inp)))
```

And then usage might look like so:

```
model = MultiEncoderSingleDecoder()

model.set_encoder(0)
# Do some training on the first feature set.

model.set_encoder(1)
# Do some more training on the second feature set.
# ...
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I am using Tensorflow, but I know TF has similar functionality when it comes to encoders. I can't ultimately evaluate if your response will work, but it will certainly point me in the right direction. Cheers.